# Why am I getting more data than I am supposed to?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    [Manager].[Name], 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] >= CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2 AS CHAR) AS DATE) AND [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] < CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AS CHAR) AS DATE)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS TotalProjectsCY2,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] >= CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AS CHAR) AS DATE) AND [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] < CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR) AS DATE)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS TotalProjectsCY1,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] >= CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR) AS DATE)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS TotalProjectsCY,
    SUM([Project].[CurrentStatusId]) AS TotalProjects
FROM [Project]
INNER JOIN [Manager] ON [Project].[ManagerId] = [Manager].[ManagerId]
WHERE 
    [Project].[CurrentStatusId] = 5
GROUP BY [Manager].[Name]
```

The goal with this is basically to return projects completed by the manager by year, dynamically. The problem that I am facing is that the totals are summing way higher that I am expecting.

I ran the following SQL query just to get the Total off all projects(to compare with the total from the above query):

```
SELECT
    [Manager].[Name],
    COUNT([Project].[CurrentStatusId]) AS Total
    FROM [Project]
INNER JOIN [Manager] ON [Project].[ManagerId] = [Manager].[ManagerId]
WHERE 
    [Project].[CurrentStatusId] = 5  AND [Manager].Name = 'MGR_NAME'
GROUP BY [Manager].[Name]
```

The total I got from the first query was `MGR_NAME 62 10 0 5035` 
The total I got from the second query was `MGR_NAME 1007`

Of course, the first query results is different than the second one since there is no splitting by year. The key difference though, is that the broken query(first) is returning **5035** as my total, verse the second query is returning the correct amount of **1007**.

**UPDATE**
So I fixed the COUNT() vs SUM() issue. The new query is:

```
SELECT
    [Manager].[Name], 
    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] >= CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2 AS CHAR) AS DATE) AND [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] < CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AS CHAR) AS DATE)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS TotalProjectsCY2,
    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] >= CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AS CHAR) AS DATE) AND [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] < CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR) AS DATE)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS TotalProjectsCY1,
    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] >= CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR) AS DATE)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS TotalProjectsCY,
    COUNT([Project].[CurrentStatusId]) AS TotalProjects
FROM [Project]
INNER JOIN [Manager] ON [Project].[ManagerId] = [Manager].[ManagerId]
WHERE 
    [Project].[CurrentStatusId] = 5
GROUP BY [Manager].[Name]
```

My new issue is it still isn't returning what it should. I again used the same test query(with a different manager)(look above). Here's what the new query and the test query spit out:

New query: `MGR_NAME 1 1 1 1`
Test query: `MGR_NAME 5`

Same issue as before, the query should be returning **5** versus what it is actually returning which is **1** as the total

**UPDATE**
If I remove the `ELSE 0` in the `CASE` statements, I get the following data returned: `MGR_NAME 0 0 0 1`. That changed the totals for the past three years from 1 to 0.

Comment: Because you're using `SUM()` in your first query and `COUNT()` in your second for the totals?

Comment: Okay, well I am a total idiot. That was it. @BJones

Comment: `CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2 AS CHAR) AS DATE)` is bad in more ways than one. Consider `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2, 1, 1)`.

Comment: @jfiggins, happens to the best of us.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks. I'll look into it.

Comment: Isn't because the 2nd query joins on BankId instead of ManagerId?

Comment: @LukStorms - Hand copied that and somehow I wrote down Bank instead of manager. the actual query uses manager.

Comment: UPDATED QUESTION

Comment: *CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AS CHAR) AS DATE)* What is it?

Comment: @JohnyL, could you clarify? Are you asking what that does?

Comment: Yes. It's unclear what's the purpose of casting number to char.

Comment: Uhm, FYI, changing it to `COUNT(CASE ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` would make it equivalent to a `COUNT(*)`.  It doesn't need the `ELSE`. The point is that a count by value doesn't count NULL's. But 0 isn't NULL.

Comment: Aside: Best practice is to _always_ specify an explicit length for strings. Ref. [`char(n)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): "When _n_ isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. If _n_ isn't specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30."

Comment: @JohnyL - I would get an error saying I couldn't convert from int to date

Comment: @LukStorms - Updated the post based off your feedback.

Comment: @HABO - So you would suggest changing `CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR) AS DATE)` to `CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4)) AS DATE)`?

Comment: @jfiggins Yes. What you are doing can be written more clearly in modern versions of SQL Server (2016 and later) as `DateFromParts( Year( GetDate() ), 1, 1 )`.

Comment: @HABO Got it, just switched that over.

Answer (score 1):

You should use COUNT(Project.CurrentStatusId) instead of SUM to get the total projects.